# Can't find the limit of this complicated expression

Tags: differential-equations

Here is the limit I am trying to calculate

```
Limit[(4 n ν Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[1 + 4 n ν, 
   1 + 4 n (µ + ν), -4 n s])/
 Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[4 n ν, 4 n (µ + ν), -4 n s],
  n -> Infinity]
```

but it doesn't work.

I tried to replace all variables (except the one we integrate over of course) by actual values but the problem persists

```
Limit[(4 n ν Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[1 + 4 n ν, 
      1 + 4 n (µ + ν), -4 n s])/
    Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[4 n ν, 
     4 n (µ + ν), -4 n s] /. ν -> 1*^-7 /. µ -> 
    1*^-7 /. s -> 0.01, n -> Infinity]
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Instead of `Limit[f[x],x->y]` you are more likely to have success with `Series[f[x],{x,y,1}]`. Also, try `FunctionExpand[f[x]]`. Finally, you could use http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/06/02/0004/ in this case. The Wolfram functions site is generally very helpful whenever you need to take a limit.